# How to change function name dynamically in python

Tags: python

I want to change the function name according to result obtained from another function but the function definition remains same How can i do this i tried the following example but it didn't work

```
def f(text):
   def x(text):
     return text+"example"
   name=x(text)
   def name(y):
     return y
   return name
p=f("hi ")
print p("hello")
print p.__name__
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hello
name
```

But i want the function name `p.__name__` as "hi example" not name

Comment: Why does one want to do this?

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN:  can't speak for the OP, but personally I have done this to tailor documentation for closures, dynamically assigning `__doc__` as well.  A closure retains the internal name, which arguably should be encapsulated.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply assign to [`__name__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-35):

```
def f(text):
   def r(y):
     return y
   r.__name__ = text + "example"
   return r
p = f("hi ")
print (p("hello")) # Outputs "hello"
print (p.__name__) # Outputs "hi example"
```

Note that a function name does not have any influence on the function's behavior though, and does not have any meaning except as a part of the string representation or a debugging aid.

Comment: I'm not so sure `__name__` is an implementation detail, it's listed as part of the [data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: @MatthewTrevor Oh, you're totally right - it's even declared writable. Fixed.